# Drupal Gmap, How can I select a sub area of "Node locations"?

Tags: google-maps, module, drupal-7

I'm putting a site together using Drupal's Gmap module to display Google map markers. Now, I was wondering, how I prompt the user for a sub location. e.g. a continent, country or city and then just show all the nodes from that certain geographical sub area? When I now click on "Node locations:, it just shows all the nodes on the whole globe (www.url.com/map/node).

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Cerr,
Can you please share solution for the query you made. I am looking for exactly same requirement.
Looking for a module which can provide a globe where user can select continent, country and city to list all nodes related to that city.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is use Google Store Locator module [drupal.org/project/google_store_locator](http://drupal.org/project/google_store_locator) . it have the features to customize the map marker pins to be your own custom icon, and you can make the map 'location aware' which allows the user to share their location with the browser, and the map will re-center and zoom based on their location.